# Как ищутся методы в суперклассе?

Tags: java

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему нижележащий код выводит:

```
1 teamlead
1 programmer
```

Собственно в чем мое непонимание? Изначально код начинает выполняется в конструкторе класса `Programmer`. Дальше происходит вызов `super(...)` и мы попадаем в родительский конструктор `TeamLead`, здесь и начинаются вопросы. В конструкторе `TeamLead` в данном конкретном случае `this` будет ссылаться на объект класса `Programmer`, тогда я не понимаю как ему вообще можно установить атрибут `numTeamLead` (почему это работает?), если `private` поля не наследуются дочерними классами.
Второй вопрос - как Java будет искать какой из методов `employ()` надо вызвать? Тот же вопрос, если модификатор у них изменить на `public`.
Если оба модификатора доступа у `employ()` заменить на `public`, то вывод будет таким:

```
0 programmer
1 programmer
```

```java
class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Programmer(1);
        }

        public static class TeamLead {
            private int numTeamLead;

            public TeamLead(int numTeamLead) {
                this.numTeamLead = numTeamLead;
                employ();
            }

            private void employ() {
                System.out.println(numTeamLead + " teamlead");
            }

        }

        public static class Programmer extends TeamLead {
            private int numProgrammer;

            public Programmer(int numProgrammer) {
                super(numProgrammer);
                this.numProgrammer = numProgrammer;
                employ();

            }

            private void employ() {
                System.out.println(numProgrammer + " programmer");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"если private поля не наследуются дочерними классами"* с чего вы это взяли

Comment: вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields) вопрос мне кажется похожий, но даже если я сформулировал криво, то объект же дочернего класса не должен иметь доступ к приватным родительским полям, а в конструкторе их меняют, какая тут логика корректная?

Answer (score 3):

Читайте про последовательность вызовов при наследовании класса.

Если вы делаете поле `private` это поле будет видимо только внутри класса и обращаться к ним можно только через методы. numTeamLead  вы ему ставите в кострукторе, который сами вызываете `super(numProgrammer)`.

Что касается если вы сделаете два метода `public void employ(){...}` то будет выполняться метод описанные в классе наследнике (`Programmer`), т.к. вы переопределите метод описанный в классе TeamLead.

Да и иерархия у вас странная логичней наоборот `TeamLead extends Programmer`, но для данного примера это не важно :).

Comment: Это пример с онлайн-курсов, не я придумал :)
про `public void employ` по идее же относится к понятию поиска метода объекта в рантайме, а вы как-то на класс завязались, разве нет? тогда почему с `private` не будет вызван метод `Programmer`, ведь `this` имеет его тип. Не понял до конца идею.

Comment: `private` метод не может быть вызван больше не откуда, только внутри объекта класса.